# Como Realizo um iteração de Checkbox e Foreach no PHP e JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, foreach

Tenho um foreach que mostra os dados recebidos do banco, quero exibir os dados apenas se o checkbox estiver marcado, mas a mostra de campos funciona apenas na primeira iteração do Foreach, segue o codigo abaixo:

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
     var checkBox = document.getElementById("VisualizarCampos");
     var conteudo = document.getElementById("Conteudo");
     if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        conteudo.style.display = "block";
     } else {
        conteudo.style.display = "none";
     }
 }
</script>
<?php foreach ($certificados as $data): ?>
  <?php $i++; ?>
   <header>
     <strong> <?php echo $i; ?> - Preencha os campos para editar os certificados</strong>
   </header>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label><input style="margin-left: 16px" type="checkbox"
            class="input-lg"
            id="VisualizarCampos" name="VisualizarCampos[<?php echo $i ?>]"                                                                 onclick="myFunction(this)">Editar</input></label>
    </div>
    <div id="Conteudo" style="display: none;margin-left: 15px">
       <input style="display: none" type="text" class="input-lg"
       value="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>" name="id">
       <input type="text" class="input-lg"
       value="<?php echo $data['nome_curso'] ?>" name="nome_curso">
       <input style="display: none" type="text" class="input-lg"
       value="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>" name="id">
       <input type="text" class="input-lg"
       value="<?php echo $data['nome_curso'] ?>" name="nome_curso">
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Abaixo segue o exemplo, tenho dois checkbox marcados mas apenas um está exibindo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O id dos inputs precisa ser único, você está usando o mesmo id toda vez. Tenta gerar um id único para cada repetição com uma variável e passar esse id como parâmetro para a função.

```
 var checkBox = document.getElementById("VisualizarCampos");
 var conteudo = document.getElementById("Conteudo"); 

 <input style="margin-left: 16px" type="checkbox" class="input-lg"id="VisualizarCampos" 
 name="VisualizarCampos[<?php echo $i ?>]" onclick="myFunction(this)">Editar</input></label>

 <div id="Conteudo" style="display: none;margin-left: 15px">
```